# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/file'

Tags: node.js

I'm running a Python script through a child process spawn in Node.js. What the python script does is take the uploaded file, extract it, and generate a JSON file in the 'resumes' folder.
when I upload a file I see the JSON generated in the 'resumes' folder. However, the program fails to find the file and return "file not found". If I upload the same file for the second time, the program finds the file.

```
  const reqFiles = []
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
  for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    reqFiles.push(url + '/public/' + req.files[i].filename)

    var ncp = require('ncp');

    ncp.limit = 16;

    ncp('./public', './resumes', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('done!');
    });

    function runScript(){
      return spawn('python3', [
        "-u", 
        path.join(__dirname, '../extract_resume_info.py'),
      ]);
    }

    const subprocess = runScript();

    subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`data:${data}`);
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`error:${data}`);
    });
    subprocess.on('close', () => {
      console.log("Closed");
    });

    console.log(req.files[i].filename)
    var file_path = reqFiles[i]
    var uploaded_file_name = req.files[i].filename
    let rawdata

    if(!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, '../resumes/'+uploaded_file_name+'.json'))) {
      console.log("File not found");
    }

    else {
      rawdata = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../resumes/'+uploaded_file_name+'.json'));
    }

    let applicant = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    console.log(applicant['name']);
```

Since I am using spawn and readfileSync, Node waits for the python script and file reading to finish. Why program can't find the file on the first run?

Comment: my guess here is npc is to slow and the python script wins the first race

Comment: @Estradiaz I tried to generate the JSON files there in the 'public' folder so that there won't be a need to copy files to 'resumes' folder. That didn't solve the issue either. Thanks!